# How can I use Pancake Swaps liquidity for my DEX?

Tags: pancakeswap, decentralized-exchange, liquidity-provider, project-fork

I created a pancakeswap forked DEX with its smart contracts and the pancakeswap SDK.

I can create pools, add liquidity & put limit orders although I want to use Pancakeswaps liquidity on my DEX.

To my understanding I would implement a swap contract for using pancakeswap's liquidity or use the pancakeswap SDK for using pancakes liquidity

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to use pancakeswap pools? Or do you want users to deposit pancake LP token in your contract?

Answer (score 0):

Pancakeswap. That's  the  protocol you're  trying to use. Not your own dex. You can access it here directly : https://pancakeswap.finance/, no need for you to make smart contracts or a website.

Comment: I know I can use the protocol directly, but that's not what I need. 

I forked Pancakeswaps contracts integrated onto my front end, but I need to use the liquidity of the Pancakeswap pools

Comment: " I created an alternative to youtube, can i put videos from youtube on it?" no you can't. Use youtube directly.

Comment: If you need to use the liquidity of pancakeswap, use pancakeswap contracts, if you want  your users to think you did something, make your own frontend for them, but still, use pancakeswap contracts.